# JQuery: Set default selection when using show/hide div

Tags: html, jquery, css

So I have this script which shows/hide a div upon selection:

```js
$('.showSingle').click(function () {

    $('.targetDiv').hide();
    $('.showSingle').removeClass('greenactive');
    $(this).addClass("greenactive")
    $('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).show();
});
```

```css
.greenactive {
    background-color: green;  border-radius: 25px; padding: 10px; color: #fff;  font-size: 14px;   color: #;
     
}

.showSingle {

 background-color: #ffffff  border-radius: 25px; padding: 10px; color: #;  font-size: 14px;   color: #; 
}

.showSingle:hover {
 background-color: #e4e6e8;  border-radius: 25px; padding: 10px; color: #535a60;  font-size: 14px;   color: #; 
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><div style="display: inline-block;" class="showSingle" target="01">Selection1</div></a>
 <a href="#"><div style="display: inline-block;" class="showSingle" target="02">Selection2</div></a>
<a href="#"><div style="display: inline-block;" class="showSingle" target="03">Selection3</div></a>

<div id="div01" class="targetDiv" style="display:none">
Target01 Content
</div>
<div id="div02" class="targetDiv" style="display:none">
Target02 Content
</div>
<div id="div03" class="targetDiv" style="display:none">
Target03 Content
</div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Right now by default it doesn't show any div.

It shows only when you click on one of the links.

How do I make so that by default the div01 would be selected and shown + my CSS applied as well?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It doesnt work because jQuery is not included.

Comment: Got it, fixed. Working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add those classes initially to the HTML and show the div and let the script take over from there

```
<a href="#">
  <div style="display: inline-block;" class="showSingle greenactive" 
  target="01">Selection1</div>
</a>
<div id="div01" class="targetDiv">
  Target01 Content
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew there was a small thing that's missing. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Logic of answer is in the comment included in the html.

```js
$('.showSingle').click(function () {

    $('.targetDiv').hide();
    $('.showSingle').removeClass('greenactive');
    $(this).addClass("greenactive")
    $('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).show();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Answer</title>
<style>
.greenactive {
    background-color: green;  border-radius: 25px; padding: 10px; color: #fff;  font-size: 14px;   color: #;
     
}

.showSingle {

 background-color: #ffffff  border-radius: 25px; padding: 10px; color: #;  font-size: 14px;   color: #; 
}

.showSingle:hover {
 background-color: #e4e6e8;  border-radius: 25px; padding: 10px; color: #535a60;  font-size: 14px;   color: #; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#"><div style="display: inline-block;" class="showSingle" target="01">Selection1</div></a>
 <a href="#"><div style="display: inline-block;" class="showSingle" target="02">Selection2</div></a>
<a href="#"><div style="display: inline-block;" class="showSingle" target="03">Selection3</div></a>

<!--if you remove the display:none from first tiem as done below it would show as defualt.--->

<div id="div01" class="targetDiv" style="">
Target01 Content
</div>
<div id="div02" class="targetDiv" style="display:none">
Target02 Content
</div>
<div id="div03" class="targetDiv" style="display:none">
Target03 Content
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your tip. Will know next time.